# Table with List iterator return unpacked list

Tags: list-manipulation

`Table` support list as iterator, for example

```
list1=Table[w, {w, Range[1., 10., 0.01]}];
```

We can confirm that list1 is packed array by

```
list1//Developer`PackedArrayQ
(*True*)
```

But now look at this

```
Table[w + ky, {w, Range[1., 10., 0.01]}, {ky, 
   Range[1., 10., 0.01]}] //Developer`PackedArrayQ
(*False*)
```

it gives unpacked array !! On the other hand

```
Table[w + ky, {w, 1., 10., 0.01}, {ky, 
   1., 10., 0.01}] //Developer`PackedArrayQ
(*True*)
```

What is wrong with List as iterator?

I am using Mathematica 10.3 on win 8

---

**Update**

egwene sedai provides a reasonable explanation.

The conclusion is that: **If there is inner loop, then outer iterator must be numerically explicit to make results packed.**

There is several work around to avoid unpacking

1.evaluate iterator explicitly

```
Table[w + ky, Evaluate@{w, Range[1., 10., 0.01]}, Evaluate@{ky, 
Range[1., 10., 0.01]}] //Developer`PackedArrayQ
(*True*)
```

2.make sub `Table` "one dimensional". Don't write nested iterator.

```
Table[Table[w + ky, {w, Range[1., 10., 0.01]}], {ky, 
Range[1., 10., 0.01]}] // Developer`PackedArrayQ
(*True*)
```

Comment: _Mathematica_ never promised to give you a packed array :D, anyway, it's a interesting observation.

Comment: @xzczd I think it might be a bug...

Comment: I don't know, it seems like a bug is when it specifically does something different than what it claims to do.   The program seems to decide based on unknown criteria whether to pack an array.  You can always use `ToPackedArray` if you need it packed of course.  Even odder I think is this result:  `Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ {Table[w, {w, Range[1., 10., 0.1]}], 
  Range[1., 10., 0.1]}`

Comment: @JasonB If it is not a bug, it is a great pitfall. Unpacking sometimes significantly harm performance.

Comment: Doesn't `Table` return UNpacked arrays most of the time though? It seems to me that the odd result is the *packed* array you get first, not the unpacked one. For instance, ``Developer`PackedArrayQ@Table[w, {w, 1, 10, 0.1}]`` returns `False`...

Comment: @MarcoB Nope, that is because of the auto compilation length of `Table` is not exceeding 250 limit

Comment: @MarcoB, if you change `0.1` to `0.01` it changes the result.

Comment: @JasonB I just notice in your first comment, you write 0.1, that caused the unpacking! Do you really mean it? It is due to auto compilation length of `Table`, this is not odd, it is mma's design

Comment: In my first comment I'm asking mathematica whether two identical lists are packed, and one says true, the other false.  I know they are identical because both `SameQ` and `Equal` tell me so

Comment: @JasonB yeah. But the storage is different, that is what `PackedArrayQ` checks.

Comment: Interesting. One could turn on `On["Packing"]` to see the warning if unpacking happens so as to manually apply `ToPackedArray` though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just a wild guess [(ref.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764774/using-array-and-table-functions-in-mathematica-which-is-best-when), but `Attributes[Table]` says `Table` has `HoldAll` attribute, which may cause `Table` to be unable to infer the type and causes the unpacking. This can be seen from turning on the unpacking warning via `On["Packing"]`. As an experiment,

```
ClearAttributes[Table, HoldAll]

Table[w + ky, {w, Range[1., 10., 0.01]}, {ky, 
   Range[1., 10., 0.01]}] // Developer`PackedArrayQ
```

> True

and then

```
SetAttributes[Table, HoldAll]

Table[w + ky, {w, Range[1., 10., 0.01]}, {ky, 
   Range[1., 10., 0.01]}] // Developer`PackedArrayQ
```

> During evaluation of In[49]:= Developer`FromPackedArray::punpack1: Unpacking array with dimensions {901}. >>
>
> False

Comment: Interesting, another possible evidence: ``With[{xx = Range[1., 10., 0.01]}, 
  Table[w + ky, {w, Range[1., 10., 0.01]}, {ky, xx}]] // Developer`PackedArrayQ``

Comment: interesting, +1

Comment: Yes, if `Table` sees a non-explicit iterator range it will go to a general evaluator rather than auto-compile. So auto-compilation is a bit weak but `Table` gets to be very flexible..

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Your comment is important. +1

Comment: @DanielLichtblau But why the one dimensional `Table` gives packed array? The iterator there is also non-explicit

Comment: I do not recall the details but I believe it involves knowing there can be no dependency of inner iterator variables on outer ones (since there are no inner iterators in the 1-D case).

Comment: @matheorem the inner/outer iterator detail by @Daniel Lichtblau can be easily verified: `Table[w + ky, {w, 1., 10., 0.01}, {ky, Range[1., 10., 0.01]}]` is **not** packed; `Table[w + ky, {w, Range[1., 10., 0.01]}, {ky, 1., 10., 0.01}]` is packed

Comment: @DanielLichtblau good explanation ! +1